# How to count specific values in a column of datagridview column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In a `DataGridView` I need to count how many duplicate values a column has.

This is my Datagridview:

[image]

For example, I'd like to count how many "X" I have in my "RisFin" column, and put the result in a textbox.

Comment: Using linq queries you can simply do many things with your grid. and the key point is casting the `Rows` collection to an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` using `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`, then you can perform any query in it, using linq.

Comment: @Marci Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it helpful, you can kindly click the check mark near the answer to make it accepted. This way it will be more useful for other users too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count what you need this way:

```
var count= this.dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
               .Count(row => row.Cells["RisFin"].Value == "X");

this.textBox1.Text = count.ToString();
```

Using linq queries you can simply do many things with your grid. and the key point is casting the `Rows` collection to an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` using `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`, then you can perform any query on it, using linq.

Comment: Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just iterate through the rows and increment your counting variable if `row.Cells[0]` is "X". Here's a LINQ solution.

```
int xCount = dataGridView.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Select(row => row.Cells["RisFin"].Value.ToString())
                .Count(s => s == "X");
```